# How to change the timezone in the particular Django admin Model?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I want to change the timezone just within the one Particular Model in Django admin, how can I do that?

As Django saves time in the database in UTC, what I want is to display the value in a particular timezone, just for one model. Not for the whole project.

For example I have a model:

```py
class Student(models.Models)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I open Django Admin for this model, I want to see the time in a particular timezone (let's say ETC) but let the Django save time in UTC.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the timezone"? Change the formatting of datetime objects?

Comment: I don't get your question... You want to change the timezone of date fields of a specific model? wouldn't it be easier to just offset them when you use them?

Comment: Database save the time in UTC, but I want display the time in the Django Admin to a particular time zone.

Comment: I found this https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-timezone-field/

Comment: is not there a way as we change timezone in django templates?

Comment: You can specify a timezone in your template using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#timezone

Comment: @IainShelvington but I am using django Admin, not the templates.

Comment: @MohsanAli add a custom admin template for your model and set the timezone there

Comment: @IainShelvington It seems very complex, to do this simple thing. Is not there a way I can do it without doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I have figured out the solution: To accomplish what I wanted to accomplish I had to made changes in the `ModelAdmin` class.

```py
    class StudentAdmin(Admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = [..., "created_at_etc", ...]
        def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
            timezone.activate("US/Eastern")
            return super(ActivityAdmin, self).add_view(
                request,
                form_url,
                extra_context
            )

        def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
            timezone.activate("US/Eastern")
            return super(ActivityAdmin, self).change_view(
                request,
                object_id,
                form_url,
                extra_context
          )

        def get_time(self, time):
            import pytz
            fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
            tz = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
            dt = time.astimezone(tz)
            return dt.strftime(fmt)

        def created_at_etc(self, student):
            return self.get_time(student.created_at)

        created_at_etc.short_description = "Created At"
```

You can activate a particular timezone in django admin by using

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.activate("US/Eastern")
```

With this you can change the timezone within a context you want to. As I am doing the same in the `add_view`, `change_view`.

First I overrided the `add_view` method that will let us create the `Student` object in the particular timezone. Second I Overrided the `change_view` so that we can edit the already existing `Student` in the particular timezone. Third I created `created_at_etc` it will display the date with respect to the particular timezone.

For more information you can use [This Article](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/01/09/managing-events-explicit-time-zones/).